# How can i receive email in visual basic with an attachment(picture) and open it in picturebox

Tags: vb.net, email, load

I wanted to ask ...I want to make a program in visual basic (2015) that it will receive an email (outlook,hotmail,gmail) with an attachment (picture) and open it in a picturebox.

Is this possible?
If yes can anyone help me with the code?

Appreciate

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, i suggest you take a read of [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you need to show some effort of your own to attract an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you'll probably need to use a Pop3 client.

See here:  [Download attachment from email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607621/download-attachment-from-email)

Once you have the email attachments downloaded locally, loading them into a picturebox is pretty straightforward.

```
PictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap( {pathToDownloadedImage} );
```

Comment: You need to remember not every Email Provider offers access to emails. some only allow to send and you need special API/OAuth access to read emails