# How to retrieve attachments from Gmail message Json

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api

I am extracting the data from gmail message Json object. I found two article which helps me to retrieve the data from json object, I can get everything from json except attachments.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/to-read-gmail-inbox-from-google-api

https://medium.com/@mendoza.paul/extract-email-signatures-with-net-and-c-from-a-gmail-account-db72d018f2af

Both example explain how we can get the data from Gmail message.

But I can't find any article which explain how to retrieve attachment as well. In my case I can't make another call to get attachment separately  because I receive whole gmail message as a Json object which I have to parse and need to save data in database.

Looking for some help.

Comment: take look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607621/download-attachment-from-email

Comment: No, this will not work for me, because I don't have user name and password, I will only receive gmail message as a json object from third party component which I can use to get all use full information regarding sender, receiver email body, subject etc... Currently struggling for attachments, not sure how to retrieve them.